# What is the purpose of "a and a or b"?

Tags: python, ternary-operator

I came across the following code in [ipython](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/master/IPython/core/magics/basic.py#L297):

```
oname = args and args or '_'
```

What is the point of that? Why not use just `args or '_'`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Python have a ternary conditional operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/does-python-have-a-ternary-conditional-operator)

Comment: This can be rewritten to `args or '_'`.

Comment: @Igle I'm aware of  `a if b else c` and `a or b` I just wandered if there is logic in what I see...

Comment: scroll further down, to https://stackoverflow.com/a/394887/1843331

Comment: @elyashiv: if `args` is "truthfull", `oname` is `args`, if not, it takes `'_'`.

Comment: @TimCastelijns So, that's just in case we want something that isn't args if args is true?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm guessing this is a hold-over from ancient (2.4 or earlier) variants of Python, where the ternary operator was not yet available to the language. According to the [Python Programming FAQ](https://docs.python.org/3.3/faq/programming.html#is-there-an-equivalent-of-c-s-ternary-operator):

> **Is there an equivalent of C’s ”?:” ternary operator?**
>
> Yes, there is. The syntax is as follows:
>
> ```
> [on_true] if [expression] else [on_false]
>
> x, y = 50, 25
> small = x if x < y else y
> ```
>
> Before this syntax was introduced in Python 2.5, a common idiom was to use logical operators:
>
> ```
> [expression] and [on_true] or [on_false]
> ```
>
> However, this idiom is unsafe, as it can give wrong results when on_true has a false boolean value. Therefore, it is always better to use the ... if ... else ... form.

The line in question could now be written as either:

```
# Option 1
oname = args if args else '_'

# Option 2
oname = args or '_'
```

Both yield the same result, since in this case the `[expression]` portion of option 1 is identical to the `[on_true]` portion. As I see it, option 2 can be considered a shortened form of option 1 for cases where `[expression]` and `[on_true]` are identical. Which one you choose to use is a personal preference.

This may give us a clue as to how long it has been since the code in question has been touched!

Comment: Good info, thanx!

Comment: I'm not sure I agree it's a duplicate. The question isn't whether or not a ternary operator exists, but _why_ the `[value] and [value] or [alternate_value]` syntax is used in this case.

Comment: Why not `oname = args or '_'`?

Comment: @tobias_k I'm referring to "should probably now be written as"

Comment: @L3viathan Oh, okay, yes, I agree. Although it could still be debateable whether that's good style.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include both possibilities, since both are valid and yield the same result. I prefer the former, since it's using the built-in ternary operator and keeps the code consistent with the idea of what was there before.

Comment: I've added further clarification. I believe option 2 is simply a shortened form of option 1, made possible by `[expression]` being identical to `[on_true]`. In the end, which you choose likely comes down to personal preference. The end result is the same (though there could be performance differences between the two).